# How to get the title of my drop down menu to change color AND stay changed when navigating through it's sub-menu

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

Basically, the word at the top of the menu changes color on hover, but i want it to stay that color when browsing the sub-menus. I have the sub-sections change color and they stay changed color when i browse their submenus but the main one will not behave.

I think it's because i have li:hover for the ones that work and a:hover for the one that doesn't (as they are not part of the a tag) but if i change it li:hover it doesn't work.

I've trimmed the code of all the fat so just the basics (and the problem) are here in this jsfiddle file. I'd like a solution using just html and css because I've not learnt js yet, and i'm sure there must be a way without it.

https://jsfiddle.net/StrangerStrings/wwcpw7cy/

```
a:hover{color: blue;}
```

is what i've got
but this won't work:

```
li:hover{color: blue;}
```

To repeat, I want the word 'Work' to stay blue when in the sub-menu.

Thank you. I hope this website answers my call! (It's my first question, also my first proper website)

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO! This site is a little different from your regular Forum (if you are familiar with those). The goal is to create a site with great answers. To do this, we discourage duplicate/similar questions. You can read more here on how to ask good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. It looks to me that there are answers to your question already, for example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19236765/change-css-dropdown-menu-color-when-any-child-is-hovered?rq=1. Contribute by upvoting things you find useful. If you want to gail points, focus on writing answers

Comment: That is the answer I'm looking for, beautiful! I tried searching for it before asking (obviously) but couldn't find it. So in a way, this website did answer my call. Thanks! I said 'Yes!' out loud when I typed it in and it works. 
Ask and thou shalt receive. (Also I'll brush up on advanced css selectors so i don't need to ask to receive)